# Kafka - Why is default serde for key and value required for groupBy and reduce?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a streaming application with [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/). My application looks as follows.

1. `flatMap` to change key and generate multiple messages from a single message.
2. `join` with a `KTable` using key from Step 1.
3. `transform` for a stateful operation.
4. `flatMap` change the key back to original key i.e., before Step 1.
5. `groupBy` with the key as in Step 4, which is actually that in, Step 1.
6. `reduce` to "merge" the records into a single message comprising a JSON array.

The net effect is to split an incoming message (with `key` as `id1`) into multiple messages (with different keys e.g., `k1`, `k2`, etc.). Enhance each of the message using `join` and `transform`. Then, change the key of each message back to `id1`. Finally, "merge" each of the enhanced message into a single message with key as `id1`.

I keep getting an error to set-up default key serde and value serde. While the default serde can be set in `application.properties`, I am not clear, why does this error even arise?

Note that, if I do not do Step 5 and Step 6, the application works successfully.

This is the Java exception I get.

```bash
2022-10-17 16:42:34,884 ERROR [org.apa.kaf.str.KafkaStreams] (app-alerts-6a7c4df8-7813-4d5d-9a86-d6f3db7c8ef0-StreamThread-1) stream-client [app-alerts-6a7c4df8-7813-4d5d-9a86-d6f3db7c8ef0] Encountered the following exception during processing and the registered exception handler opted to SHUTDOWN_CLIENT. The streams client is going to shut down now. : org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Please specify a key serde or set one through StreamsConfig#DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:627)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:551)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Please specify a key serde or set one through StreamsConfig#DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultKeySerde(StreamsConfig.java:1587)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.keySerde(AbstractProcessorContext.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SerdeGetter.keySerde(SerdeGetter.java:47)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.WrappingNullableUtils.prepareSerde(WrappingNullableUtils.java:63)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.WrappingNullableUtils.prepareKeySerde(WrappingNullableUtils.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.initStoreSerde(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:195)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:144)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.registerStateStores(ProcessorStateManager.java:212)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:231)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:865)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:747)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:589)
        ... 1 more
```

These are `StreamsConfig` values:

```bash
        acceptable.recovery.lag = 10000
        application.id = machine-alerts
        application.server = 
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
        buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
        built.in.metrics.version = latest
        cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10240
        client.id = 
        commit.interval.ms = 1000
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler
        default.dsl.store = rocksDB
        default.key.serde = null
        default.list.key.serde.inner = null
        default.list.key.serde.type = null
        default.list.value.serde.inner = null
        default.list.value.serde.type = null
        default.production.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DefaultProductionExceptionHandler
        default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
        default.value.serde = null
        max.task.idle.ms = 0
        max.warmup.replicas = 2
        metadata.max.age.ms = 500
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = DEBUG
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        num.standby.replicas = 0
        num.stream.threads = 1
        poll.ms = 100
        probing.rebalance.interval.ms = 600000
        processing.guarantee = at_least_once
        rack.aware.assignment.tags = []
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        repartition.purge.interval.ms = 30000
        replication.factor = -1
        request.timeout.ms = 40000
        retries = 0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        rocksdb.config.setter = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
        state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
        task.timeout.ms = 300000
        topology.optimization = none
        upgrade.from = null
        window.size.ms = null
        windowed.inner.class.serde = null
        windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
```

Comment: Please add your kafka configuration and exception you get.

Comment: Removing quarkus tag since stacktrace is isolated to only Streams API

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Quarkus works, However, the Serde error in groupBy statements is common when you start using Kafka Streams. The groupBy statement creates an internal and compacted topic where the data is going to be grouped by key, (Internally your stream application is going to send messages to that topic) for that reason you should specify the Serde for your GroupBy statement at the code level if the value or key are different types as default key and value Serde in your Stream properties.

```
KGroupedStream<String, User> groupedStream = stream.groupByKey(
    Serialized.with(
      Serdes.String(), /* key */
      new CustomUserSerde())     /* value */
  );
```

In the above example, I'm using the desired Serdes in the group statement, not at the property level.

Comment: What package should be imported for `Serialized.with()`? VSCode doesn't list this method for `groupByKey()`.

Comment: We probably need [`Grouped<K,V>.with`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Grouped.html#with-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde-)

Comment: Exactly that depends on your Kafka Streams versions.