# Kafka - ClassCastException when reducing a KGroupedStream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, reduce

I want to "merge" records in the reduce operation such that, the input records are "reduced" to entries in an array. I keep getting an error as follows.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @28c97a5)
```

Here is the reducer code.

```java
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonObjectSerde()))
        .reduce(new Reducer<JsonObject>() {
          public JsonObject apply(JsonObject v1, JsonObject v2) {
            ArrayList<JsonObject> data = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();

            data.add(v1.getJsonObject("k1"));
            data.add(v2.getJsonObject("k1"));

            JsonObject aggr = new JsonObject();
            aggr.put("meta",
                v1.getJsonObject("k0"));
            aggr.put("data", new JsonArray(data));

            return aggr;
          }
        })
```

The error is at `data.add(v1.getJsonObject("k1"));`. Why does this statement cause the `ClassCastException`?

Comment: Please show your `StreamsConfig` definition and the full stacktrace. Also, you should consider using `JsonArray` directly here instead of intermediate `ArrayList`.

Comment: Streams configuration is default. My first attempt used `JsonArray` directly - same result. Anything in particular in stack trace?

Comment: Streams configuration as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74099576/16433289

Comment: As listed there, your `default.value.serde = null`, so without `Materialized.with` (second param to reduce method) / `Grouped.with`, it cannot easily infer types. Also, Kafka includes Jackson, so I'm not sure about using VertX JSON classes

Comment: I am still getting the `ClassCastException` after using `Materialized.with` for `reduce`. The weird thing is, the error comes after 1 message written to the output topic. Is the 2nd `reduce` some way different from the first `reduce` iteration?